# Sql Server Msg 2110

Tags: sql-server

I can't figure out how to solve the following error:

> Msg 2110, Level 15, State 1, Procedure store, Line 113
>   Cannot alter trigger 'store_10' on 'Users' because this trigger does not belong to this object. Specify the correct trigger name or the correct target object name.

The above Trigger was created using the following syntax (and no error msg was generated):

```
Alter trigger store_10 ON Users FOR UPDATE
```

Comment: What's confusing about the error message?  The message is pretty clear: `Users` doesn't have a trigger named `store_10`.  You can't `ALTER` something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Things often get confused if there's been an `sp_rename` on one or both of the objects at some point in the past.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. As I mentioned, I created the trigger and no error message wes generated. But I can't see the created trigger in the trigger folder of the table 'Users'.                                                               CREATE TRIGGER store_10 ON Users FOR UPDATE

AS

Begin
 Select * from deleted
 Select * from inserted 
End

GO

Comment: P.S I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014 and it's a new world to me.

Comment: Has your `Users` table any schema, probably dbo ? what about trying 

`Alter [dbo].[trigger store_10] ON [Users] FOR UPDATE` Also, Refreshing db is preferable, Management studio can be slow sometimes. Check also which db you are using.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Did you click on refresh in the object explorer (header) sometimes you need to do so a couple of times.

Comment: @ Siyual: The trigger exists, I confirmed it's existence using the following codes: SELECT 
     T.name AS [Trigger Name]
    ,O.name AS [Table Name]
FROM sys.[triggers] T
INNER JOIN sys.[Objects] O
    ON O.[object_id] = T.[parent_id]
;

Comment: @cybersin: I tried your syntax but it outputs the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run this query to see what triggers you have assigned to what tables in the database:

```
SELECT 
     T.name AS [Trigger Name]
    ,O.name AS [Table Name]
FROM sys.[triggers] T
INNER JOIN sys.[Objects] O
    ON O.[object_id] = T.[parent_id]
;
```

That might give you some indication of where things are going haywire.

Just make sure you're running the query in a new query window opened on the same database where the problem is occurring.

Once you have that information, you should be able to figure out what the issue is.

**First Edit:**

Can you try running this query to get the trigger definition and post the result as an edit to your question, please?

```
EXECUTE sys.sp_helptext 'store_10';
```

Comment: It works. I can see the triggers which I created in the results table. But I still can't see them in the object explorer.